# Setting up Intel Giga PHY I217V on Debian 2.6.32 kernel

Tags: debian, kernel, drivers, ethernet

Trying to getting the Intel integrated network card driver (Giga PHY Intel I217V) working on Debian (kernel 2.6.32) but I'm having issues.

I've downloaded the driver from the Intel website and completed the following:

Downloaded the source e1000e driver from the Intel Driver Site

```
$ cd ~/e1000e
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
$ rmmod e1000e; modprobe e1000e
```

`lspci`, `dmesg` and `lsmod` shows that the Intel Ethernet is there but it is not showing up in `ifconfig -a`. There is no `eth0`

I have tried restarting; resetting the bios but still no network connection.

NB: This is a USB bootable drive; I have a Ubuntu 13.10 bootable driver (kernel version 3.11) that works fine (network card is picked up without having to install Intel drivers). I wanted to know how to fix this in Debian kernel 2.6.32 (32bit)

Answer (score -1):

```
ifconfig eth xxx
```

Assigns an IP address

Comment: The common (natural) language used on this site is English. The grammar/spelling doesn't have to be perfect. El lenguaje (naturales) común  que se utiliza en este sitio es Inglés. La gramática / ortografía no tiene que ser perfecto.